# Постоянная проверка условия в фоне

Tags: python, python-3.6

Как сделать чтобы постоянно в фоновом режиме проверялось условие допустим: программа постоянно проверяла при этом всем выполняется другой блок кода, а как  только условие верное мы его выполняем хоть даже оно на первой строке кода, а мы на 300

```
morozhenoye_upalo = False

if morozhenoye_upalo = True: print ("podnyat")

morozhenoye_upalo = True
```

Comment: То есть первый алгоритм является долгим (или бесконечным), и при нажатии он прерывается и начинается другой?

Comment: Ну смотри у меня есть типо такой алгоритмик  после покупаем мороженого мы сожем ходить с ним когда угодно и делать что угодно но в любой он может упасть и условие "мороженое упало" выполняетса и у нес запускаетса цыкл поднять мороженое и выбросить его и так далее. Я хочу узнать как зделать так что бы условие проверялось постоянно (не через while или for ) ну тип как в фоновом режыме когда у нас какойто алгоритм выполняетса

Answer (score 9, accepted):

возможно вам подойдут [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

`b_file.py`:

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def check():
    print('check')
```

`a_file.py`:

```
from b_file import check
<...>
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RepeatTimer(120, check).start()  # функция check будет выполняться в отдельном потоке каждые 2 минуты
    <...>
```

Comment: Смотрите я посути новичок и я хочу узнать как зделать что бы условие проверялось всегда, пример кода:

Comment: как сделать что бы условия мороженое упало стало верным даже когда оно совпадает только в коде ниже его

Answer (score 3):

По мне, лучше сделать свойство и/ли функцию

Через функцию:

```
#via Function
fldIceCreamDropped = False;

def SetIceCreamDropped(Value):
  fldIceCreamDropped = Value
  if (fldIceCreamDropped):
    print('Ахтунг ахтунг')

...
...

SetIceCreamDropped(True)
```

Через св-во:

```
#via Property
class APerson(object):
    
  def __init__(self):
    self.ficeCreamDropped = False;

  def iceCreamDroppedSet(self, value):
    print("Setting an Ice");
    self.ficeCreamDropped = value
    if ( self.ficeCreamDropped ):
      print("Dropped !!!");
      
  iceCreamDropped = property(None, iceCreamDroppedSet);

  
man = APerson()
...
...
man.iceCreamDropped = True
```

Соответственно, как только будет задано значение - именно в этот момент произойдёт обработка падения мороженого.

Значение не будет проверятся всегда (да и не должно), но отработает именно тогда, когда значение будет изменено.

Comment: А есть ссылка на документацию к этим свойствам и функциям или какие-то обучалки на Ютубе?

Comment: Конечно есть, поиском и нашёл их:
в почти любом поисковике ввести
"Python function definition"
"Python class definition"
"Python Property"
и попадаем на большой выбор документации

Comment: Спасибо выручили 