# Как сделать так что бы после определенной функции исполнялась та функция которую мне надо

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Здраствуйте! Возникла проблема, надо что бы после того как в функции `answer` посчитала сколько раз нажали кнопку. После этого дать один ответ из трех.
Писал код в `callback_query_handler` но если на кнопку нажмут 10 человек то после 5 секунд человеку который отправлял запрос придёт 10 одинаковых ответов.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):

    global s_yes
    global s_no
    
    if call.data == 'yes':
        s_yes += 1
        
    if call.data == 'no':
        s_no += 1

    time.sleep(5)
    
@bot.message_handler(func = lambda message: True)
def replay_answer(message):
    s_n = s_no
    s_y = s_yes

    global user_id
    
    if s_y > s_n:
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Ты прошел')
    elif s_y < s_n :
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Извены')
    elif s_y == s_n:
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Подожди')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(...)

yes = {}
no = {}

<...>


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        if call.message.chat.id in yes:
            yes.update({call.message.chat.id: {'yes': yes[call.message.chat.id]['yes'] + 1}})
        else:
            yes.update({call.message.chat.id: {'yes': 1}})

    elif call.data == 'no':
        if call.message.chat.id in no:
            no.update({call.message.chat.id: {'no': no[call.message.chat.id]['no'] + 1}})
        else:
            no.update({call.message.chat.id: {'no': 1}})
    print('Y', yes)
    print('N', no)

    # noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        if yes[call.message.chat.id]['yes'] > no[call.message.chat.id]['no']:
            print('yes > no')
        elif yes[call.message.chat.id]['yes'] < no[call.message.chat.id]['no']:
            print('yes < no')
        elif yes[call.message.chat.id]['yes'] == no[call.message.chat.id]['no']:
            print('yes = no')
    except Exception:
        pass
```

при первом нажатии, допустим, на `yes`:

```
>>> Y {id: {'yes': 1}}
    N {}
```

в той же сессии, при нажатии на `no`:

```
>>> Y {id: {'yes': 1}}
    N {id: {'no': 1}}
    yes = no
```

*пример нужно оптимизировать*

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень помогли, но есть еще один вопрос как сделать так что бы, допустим, после 1 минуты были посчитанные голоса и отправились тому кто давал запрос. С тем как отправить я разобрался но вот время.... А вот таймер не могу понять как сделать

Comment: Как уже писал в вопросе делал через `time.sleep()`, но оно не работает, точнее работает но не так как надо.... Оно тип, если два раза нажать на кнопку `yes` то после, например, 10 сек оно отправит `yes` и потом после еще 10 сек отправит еще раз `yes`

Comment: возможно вам подойдёт этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140444/234134 для проверки в фоне

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!